# Android: Logging or exception stack trace on real device

Tags: android

When testing on real Android devices, I run my application from within Eclipse and have access  to the logs and errors using DDMS and LogCat.

However, there is one device I own that I cannot connect to my PC, and therefore I cannot view on DDMS.

When this application loads, it throws an Exception. However, I have no idea what this Exception is.
How can I view such errors or logs on a real device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install a logcat viewer such as [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en). It provides various ways for you to view, save or share the log output.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more generally, you can include [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/), whenever your application crashes on your clients' devices, it will automatically send the crash report to you, including useful info like stacktrace, Android OS version, screen dimensions, device name, etc...

I didn't realize how buggy my applications really are in the field until I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of logcat reader apps - like CatLog or aLogcat, capable of viewing logs, filtering or saving them to the external storage. Just search the Market for "logcat".